# Create service in a module in Ballerina lang

Tags: ballerina

I've the following file structure:

```
│   Ballerina.toml
│   main.bal
│
├───modules
│   ├───http_listener
│   │       http_listener.bal
│   │       
│   └───question
│       │   .gitignore
│       │   question.bal
│       │   service.bal
│       │
│       └───tests
│               question_test.bal
│               service_test.bal
│
│
└───tests
```

In `main.bal` contains the following service:

```
import question_management.http_listener;
service / on http_listener:QuestionManagementListener {
    resource function get status() returns string {
        return "UP";
    }
}
```

http_listener is just a listener:

```
import ballerina/http;

public listener http:Listener QuestionManagementListener = new(9095);
```

The issue I'm facing is  that a service defined in `question/service.bal` is not serving traffic. The service is defined as follows:

```
import question_management.http_listener;

service /questions on http_listener:QuestionManagementListener {
    resource function get allQuestions() returns string {
        Question|error q = new Question("Test", ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]);
        json[] qarray = [];
        if(!(q is error)) { qarray.push(q.toJson()); }
        return qarray.toJsonString();
    }
}
```

However when I start the program, only the `/status` endpoint is responding as expected. The
`questions/allQuestions` is respnding with 404

```
no matching resource found for path : /questions/allQuestions , method : GET
```

If I move the service from `question/service.bal` to `main.bal`,`/questions/allQuestions` starts working correctly. However I want to have my service definitions into their own module if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a module to be initialized it needs to be imported directly or indirectly in the program. This applies to modules in the same package too. Since `question_management.question` is not imported directly in the default module or in a module that is imported by the default module, the service in `question_management.question` is not initialized or attached to the listener, which is why this error is observed.

A module can be imported using the import prefix `_` to include it in the program without using the symbols in it. This will result in the module being initialized, and the service will then be initialized and attached to the listener [1].

Adding `import question_management.question as _;` in the default module (`main.bal`) will  result in the service in `question_management.question` being attached to the listener, and invoking `/questions/allQuestions` should work as expected.

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/module-lifecycle

Comment: We are planning to address this use case with this issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/68052493/8887779